# Key Value parsing java

Tags: java

Hi i have a line like this "NameThoufiqAge21LocationTN" where my keys are Name, Age , Location
I am looking towards a code that could parse the above line into key value pairs as

Name Thoufiq
Age 21
Location TN

Comment: Try using basic string methods. You can find the [documentation for string here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, but it works. Hope you get the idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "NameThoufiqAge21LocationTN";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern
            .compile("Name(\\w+)Age(\\d+)Location(\\w+)")
            .matcher(str);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Name=" + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("Age=" + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("Location=" + matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name=Thoufiq
Age=21
Location=TN
```

Comment: Your program would break if the person's name was [Tommy Agee](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommie_Agee)...

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String line = "NameThoufiqAge21LocationTN";
    boolean newKey = true;
    for (char a : line.toCharArray()) {
        if (a < 97 && !newKey) { // http://www.asciitable.com/
        newKey = true;
        System.out.print(" " + a);
        } else {
        System.out.print(a);
        newKey = false;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name Thoufiq Age 21 Location TN
```

Comment: Why not use `Character.isUpperCase(a)` instead of `a < 97`? Did I missed something?

Comment: @Harmlezz The data was separated by capital letters or numbers so I wanted to capture all the letters and numbers and also wanted to include any funky characters as a capital letter. I think the truth is I put < 97 because it was so short.

Comment: What if the name was McKenzie?

Comment: @jahroy I was assuming I didn't know the names of the keys ahead of time and that the data was capital delimited. What if the person entering the data wrote in only lowercase letters but I searched for the name of the keys and like you said the person could be named Agee.

Comment: The bottom line is the OP specified nothing about his requirements so we have no clue what he needs.